# Within the Case condition gets error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I have this sql

```
DECLARE @CurrentLocation geography; 
SET @CurrentLocation  = geography::Point(@Latitude,@Longitude,4326)

SELECT 
    ID,
    RestaurantTitle,
    CuisineName,
    Latitude, Longitude,
    MinimumOrder,
    ImagePath,
    CASE 
       WHEN r.OpeningTimeType IN ('24*7') 
          THEN r.OpeningTimeType 
          ELSE r.Breakfast_OpenTime 
    END AS OpenTime,
    CASE 
       WHEN r.Breakfast_OpenTime > CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
            AND R.Dinner_CloseTime < CONVERT (time, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
          THEN 'PRE ORDER' 
          ELSE 'ORDER NOW' 
    END AS BUTTONNAME,
    ROUND(ROUND(GeoLocation.STDistance(@CurrentLocation), 0) / 1609.34, 0) AS Distance  
FROM 
    [dbo].[tbl_Restaurant1] r 
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 
         CuisineName + ',' 
     FROM
         tbl_Cuisine 
     WHERE
         tbl_Cuisine.ID IN (SELECT CuisineID_FK 
                            FROM tbl_Restaurant_Cuisine 
                            WHERE r.ID = RID_FK) 
     FOR XML PATH('')) D (CuisineName)
WHERE 
    @CurrentLocation.STDistance([GeoLocation]) <= 40000
```

When I ran this SQL, an exception is thrown:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Here are the columns:

```
ID int
RestaurantTitle varchar(50)
Latitude decimal(10, 6)
Longitude decimal(10, 6)
MinimumOrder int 
ImagePath varchar(50) 
OpeningTimeType varchar(50)
breakfast_OpenTime time
```

Comment: Your first case statement seems to be trying to coalesce a string (`r.OpeningTimeType`) with a date and/or time (`r.Breakfast_OpenTime`), which is probably what is producing the error. For a case statement, the values you return need to all be able to be converted to the same data type (the data type with the [highest precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx)). e.g. '24*7' can't be converted to a date and/or time.

Comment: (A possible fix is just to cast your `r.Breakfast_OpenTime` as a varchar in the first case statement).

Comment: fix that issue by changing first case statement by CASE WHEN r.OpeningTimeType ='24*7' THEN   r.OpeningTimeType  ELSE CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(Breakfast_OpenTime AS TIME),100)    END AS  OpenTime .thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** that returns exactly one atomic value. Therefore, **all** different options of the `CASE` must return the **same datatype** (or at least compatible ones) - and this is not so in your `CASE` here:

```
CASE 
   WHEN r.OpeningTimeType IN ('24*7') 
      THEN r.OpeningTimeType 
      ELSE r.Breakfast_OpenTime 
END AS OpenTime,
```

`OpeningTimeType` is `varchar(50)`, while `Breakfast_OpenTime` is of type `time`. Therefore, SQL Server needs to convert one value into the common return type.

Based on the [SQL Server type precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx), it will try to convert both possible return values into `TIME` and that's where it fails.

So in order to fix this, it's up to **you** to make sure the `CASE` variations all return the **same datatype** so that no implicit conversions need to take place. Since you obviously cannot guarantee that `OpeningTimeType` can be converted to a `TIME`, you need to do the opposite - convert the `Breakfast_OpenTime` to a `VARCHAR(50)`:

```
CASE 
   WHEN r.OpeningTimeType IN ('24*7') 
      THEN r.OpeningTimeType 
      ELSE CAST(r.Breakfast_OpenTime AS VARCHAR(50))
END AS OpenTime,
```